# Difference between explicit delegate and method group in a thread constructor

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I tested the following lines of code (not at the same time, of course) and as far as I can see, they achieve the same result. Being a cautious person, I can imagine that there's a difference between what/how they do stuff but that I'm ignorant of it due to lack of appropriate observation sample.

```
Thread whee = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate { someObject.Start(); });
Thread whoo = new Thread(someObject.Start);
Thread whaa = new Thread(() => { someObject.Start(); });
```

What, if anything, is the difference between the above? Is that information, perhaps, available somewhere in **almost** plain sight and I'm missing it due to confusion?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first and third calls are the exact same thing. Regarding these other two:

```
//Thread whee = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate { someObject.Start(); });
//or, using a lambda expression, 
Thread whee = new Thread(() => someObject.Start());

Thread whoo = new Thread(someObject.Start);
```

In the first one, you create a delegate that closes over (or captures) the `someObject` variable. When the thread calls your delegate, it will evaluate which object the variable points to, and call `Start` on it.

In the second one, `someObject` is eagerly evaluated.

```
Thread whee = new Thread(() => someObject.Start());
Thread whoo = new Thread(someObject.Start);

someObject = someOtherObject;

whee.Start();
whoo.Start();
```

If you assign a new object to your `someObject` variable before starting the threads, you'll notice that:

- the first thread calls `Start` on `someOtherObject`, because the closure variable was lazily-evaluated.
- the second thread calls `Start` on the original instance `someObject` pointed to, because the variable was eargerly-evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Set `someObject = null;` after your code and before starting the threads to see for yourself.

Your samples are effectively the difference between getting an object, and creating a method that can get that object at some point in the future.  The code is only the same of "that object" in this case, `someObject` never changes.

Comment: would be better to see short explanation, or add this like a comment, cause this is a suggession, basically...